# What is the 'correct' way to caption stacked images for comparison?

Tags: thesis, formatting

I am editing my thesis, and cannot find any resources on the best way to caption multiple images stacked side-by-side or top-to-bottom for comparison. I quickly put together an example of how I think I should do it.

[stacked top to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCemA.png)

[stacked left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOwFE.png)

I think if each image was non-related, then it would be appropriate to caption them as different images, but if they are similar, then I am thinking of using one caption but labelling each image alphabetically.

I am in the UK and the thesis is MSc level, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; what is wrong with either of these?

Comment: Doesn't it purely depend on the shape of the images?

Comment: @BryanKrause, I am asking if there is some sort of academic standard or best approach to follow when it comes to captioning multiple images.  I provided those as examples, and wanted to know if I followed an appropriate style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that a "figure" can be composed of many "images", because the possibility of visually inspecting them at the same time is what conveys the message of the figure.

You can find many examples in peer-reviewed papers, for example multiple similar images:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Image-compression-comparison-of-Lena-image-a-Original-Image-Image-compressed-by-b_fig7_228959932

or figure 6 here for heterogneous pictures that needs to be seen together:
https://nhess.copernicus.org/articles/21/3465/2021/#&gid=1&pid=1